# Z̡̬a̧̯̔l̆̓g̛̘̟o̡ generator

Tags: code-golf, string, unicode

Write a program or function that transforms an input string into [Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work) text.

For example, for an input string `Zalgo`, a possible output might look like:

> Z̗̄̀ȧ̛̛̭̣̖̇̀̚l̡̯̮̠̗̩̩̥̭̋̒̄̉̏̂̍̄̌ģ̨̭̭̪̯̫̒̇̌̂o̢̟̬̪̬̙̝̫̍̈̓̅̉̇

### Zalgoification specs

- Each letter (upper or lower case) must be zalgoified, and nothing else (spaces, punctuation).
- The [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) that can be placed on letters here are all those between U+0300  ̀  and U+032F  ̯
- Each letter must have a total number of combining characters on it (above and under combined) which is randomly chosen according to a normal distribution of mean 10 and standard deviation 5 (If a negative number is chosen, 0 combining characters must be added).
- Each combining character placed on a letter is chosen uniformly at random between the 48 possible combining characters (see 2nd item).

### Inputs, Outputs

- Input is a single line string that contains only characters between ASCII 32 (space) and ASCII 126 (tilde). No line breaks. You may assume there is at least one letter in the string. The input can be taken as command line argument, function parameter, or STDIN.
- Output is the Zalgoified string. It can be written to a file, or printed to STDOUT, or returned from a function. A trailing line feed is fine. **The output doesn't have to display properly in your interpreter/whatever, as long as when you copy it to a Stack Exchange answer it displays properly like here**.

### Test cases

- The Zalgo example above.
- Input: `Programming Puzzles & Code Golf`

Possible output:

> P̢̭̟̟̮̍̅̏̍̀̊̕̚̚r̢̫̝̟̩̎̔̅̈̑o̡̠̣̪̠̍̈̐̏̌̆g̡̬̯̟̠̩̎̐́̅̚ȑ̢̨̩̠̙̭̤̩̟̔̕ą̟̟̯̠̪̜́̉̒̎̂̍̃́̚̚̚m̪̈̅̈m̨̛̛̪̤̟̔̍̓i̢̛̬̠̠̇̈̂̓̒̀̋̔̚̚n̛̝̩̜̓̐̑̅̅g̨̩̪̊ P̨̧̢̟̙̮̋̆ų̨̙̞̙̫̤̫̭̊̓̒̃̒̚z̜̤̮̪̫̄̌̃̈̉̑̋́̕z̡̥̯̠̬̜̥̑̌̓̌̋́̅ľ̫̙̟̪̖̉ė̢̨̘̦̘̖s̛̜̙̘̚ & C̨̠̟̯̟̙̠̉̄̄́̄̑̈̔̆̀ö̭̟̗̯̥̏̐̄̏̌d̞̬̀̆́̀é̟̙̩̗̙̣̋̎̌̌̋ Ğ̨̡̧̡̣̪̝̝̘̩̮̉̋̀̉̉̕̕ọ̠̠̘̟̑̇́̀̃̎̓̋̚ḽ̡̢̟̪̥̍̍̅̀́̎̆̕f̧̢̪̠̠̀̉̒̍̍̊́

- Input: `Golf is a club and ball sport in which players use various clubs to hit balls into a series of holes on a course in as few strokes as possible.`

Possible output:

> Ǧ̡̧̄̐̊ò̡̞̟̖̌́̄́̆̈̒l̡̬̣̜̫̞̘̪̇̈̏̊̆̃̑̉̓̒f̙̐̍̇́̐̍̉ į̦̘̝̣̊̒̎̚s à̡̛̠̜̙̣̙̞̣̗̯̝̘̩̅̊̓̄̒̃ ć̬̗̫̯̫̎́̚l̒̎̋ű̯̜̑̎b̯̣̮̭̤̃̊́ a̡̨̟̘̭̣̍̈̀̃̎́̐̋̆̂ń̨̖̭̝̬̘̦̣̓̇̚̕d̨̤̣̙̜̪̖̪̍̓̔̍̔̃̒̍̆̏̚̚̕̚ ḃ̬̪̇̕a̡̟̖̬̬̖̬̋́̎̎̔̄̏̒̑̚l̨̖̜̬̠̭̭̇l̡̡̛̛̬̤̆̔̑̍ s̠̙̣̠̖̜̜̅p̤̖̃́̅̕̕ǫ̢̥̬̠̞̭̭̘̟̞̋̊̌r̡̛̞̬̈̇̑̎̄̚t̟̩̏̀ ï̡̧̢̨̜̜̝̝̜̜̫̔̇̂̔̐n̞̖̫̪̟̤̦̫̂̓̍̑̆̒̚ w̨̧̟̠̯̜̙̘̏̎̈̆̂̅̔hi̧̝̖̗̖̒̆̆̈̚ć̪̜̫̖̠̣̞̋̈́̀̌̋h̢̢̨̥̮ p̜̣̋̔̆l̨̧̛̘̫̝̙̠̯̂̑̌̈̒̐ā̩̗̟̐ẏ̢̛̫̠̦̤̫̞̦̯̥̜̀̀̈̅̉̈̄ẹ̡̑̔̄̉̀̎̒̑r̛̫̭̤̋̄̓̀̅̓ș̜̯̆̋̒̍̔ ų̛̘̭̜̝̈̃̂̅̌̍̆̚s̡̡̡̨̫̥̪̋̈̀̀̆ê̢̡̡̥̖̮̞̫̪̥̘̥̯̎́ v̡̢̢̟̠̞̬̥̩̣̫̫̦̞̂̐̓̇ặ̢̧̙̝̥̪̗̆̎̓ŗ̦̙̩̑̒̕í̫̣̊̚ō̡̧̤̘̟̩̠̫̗̃̍̉̊̕ụ̡̪̠̈̈́̊̅s̢̢̘̤̝̪̀̎̅ c̡̢̛̖̫̗̑̒̆́̎̚l̥̥̖̘̉̎̓̔̀̔ų̘̘̣̟̃̆̓̉̏̅̓̂́̇b̡̝̗̙̗̮̖̩̗̦̏̌̏š̛̮̣̮̜̒̓̌ ṭ̣̫̗̮̙̈̔̅̂̎̃̌̈ò̮̘̍̅̃̃̅̚̕ ḩ̜̞̮̠̇i̮t̝̗̦̖̮̞̗̩̞̤̎̍̒̐ bȁ̢̮̩̝̣̉ļ̛̮̘̏ĺ̨̖̮̑s̢̬̪̗̬̖̟̅̀ i̢̗̖̊̃ń̨̧̛̫̮̞̎t̡̗̞̩̙̑̐̏̔̏ơ̧̯̮̦̖̇̆̔ ạ̧̉̍̚ s̤̬̫̠̉e̎̃r̟̪̥̗̜̥̍̆̍̇̕̕i̧̧̭̝̫̪̯̖̞̪̅̇̎̈̐̅̍ȇ̟̬́̄̃̐̊̕s̢̢̛̝̤̙̭̘̩̩̍̑̂̈̀̀̍̄̔̒̒ o̡̢̘̩̣̅̐̆̌̂̉̇̆̋̕f̡̯̜̝̘̮̠̖̐̂̒̃̚̕ h̪̘̫̪́ǫ̭̦̔̋̆̚̕l̢̡̧̨̙̯̤̔̅̓̆̑̍́ȅ̪̬̝̙̅̋̍s̪̖̭̫̪̟̖̐̀̕ ǫ̦̠̫̍̊̉̄̚n̐̎̂̀ ą̡̛̛̤̦̪̣̭̈̐̂̎ c̪̩̠̗̟̜̘̐̂̈̐̑̏̈ọ̡̡̙̫̞̜̐̇̄̓̏u̥̖̙̝̔̂̎̅̚̚r̙̜̬̭̠̮̙̙̪̫̝̙̬̥̥̯̐́̈́̊̈̍̍ș̀́e̞̜̒̌̚ ĩ̧̦̝̪̆n̛̞̞̆̆̀ a̟̅̐̈̍̉̚̚̕ş̫̭̍̐̚ f̘̝̠̪̦̜́̌̍̇̀̕e̩̫̣̊̎̇̚w̪ ŝ̨̨̠̠̝̦̣̜̦̗̮̞̞̥̥̅̄̄̕t̢̡̢̙̞̟̩̭̤̅̎̌̒̃̇̕r̞̤̙̄̊̃̇̅̈̏̈̌ǫ̝̬̀̋̏̐̌̈k̡̢̧̪̭̝̙̆̈̒̀ȩ̛̙̣̠̗̞̮̅̅s̙̣̒̉̎́̂̅ à̧̛̖̘̞̫̘̎̃̀̑̎̕̕s̢̟̟̭̩̈̏̇ p̣̟̭̗̪̜̫̦̝̣̎̋̎̀̐̏o̧̢̪̮̤̦̎́̐̒̀̚̕s̛̯̦̗̬̬̊̊̄̓̐̉̏́̚s̢̠̣̬̥̬̔̅̕̕i̡̠̣̣̫̞̣̮̥̟̅̎̇̄̋̌̌̇b̡̧̡̖̖̃̄̋̈̋l̢̢̙̪̣̉̉̐̑̆ẹ̢̒̎.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes ẁ̨̛̭̙̥̖̏̏̐̐̉̃̅̚i̜̟̭̤̞̘̗̐̐̔̈̍̋̏̚n̘̯̥̩̗̯̠̘̮̋̈̃̀̊̉̎̈̕s̛̬̦̙̮̩̜̄̑̐́̎̆̚.

Comment: First issue I have when attempting this. How to create a set of numbers that conform to a known mean and standard deviation?

Comment: @Luminous The vast majority of languages have built-in or libraries to roll random numbers that follow a normal distribution. If your language of choice only has uniform distribution random numbers, there are ways to use them to get a normal distribution (e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform))

Comment: I'm not sure how Zalgoification works, but does it work on numbers as well? and if so, do we have to apply it to numbers here as well?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs No, only letters

Comment: ... You called?

Comment: Interesting "Z̡̬a̧̯̔l̆̓g̛̘̟o̡" doesn't render correctly in the [Hot Network Questions](http://imgur.com/Dgz01Eg)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma It does display properly for me in the hot questions...

Comment: @fatalize it must be a font or browser issue then. (Chrome on OSX)

Comment: @Luminous Just [hardcode it](https://xkcd.com/221/)!

Comment: Chrome asked me if I wanted to translate this page.

Comment: The title should have been "Tony the Pony He Comes"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## CJam, <s>57</s> <s>56</s> <s>49</s> 47 bytes

*Thanks to Sp3000 for saving 7 bytes.*

```
q{_eu_el={Pmrmc1.mrml-50*mq*A+mo{48mr'̀+}*}|}/
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7B_eu_el%3D%7BPmrmc1.mrml-50*mq*A%2Bmo%7B48mr'%CC%80%2B%7D*%7D%7C%7D%2F&input=Programming%20Puzzles%20%26%20Code%20Golf)

## Explanation

This uses Box–Muller for the normal distribution: the basic algorithm generates two uniform variables in the range `[0,1)`, `U` and `V` and then computes two normally distributed values from them. We only need one and the simpler one is `X = √(-2 ln U) cos(2πV)`. This generates a distribution with mean `0` and standard deviation `1`, so we need to multiply it by `5` to correct the standard deviation and add `10` to correct the mean. We can also simplify the cosine, because omitting the `2` gives the same distribution. So we compute `X = √(-50 ln U) cos(πV) + 10` before rounding to get the number of combining marks.

Here is the code:

```
q{          e# For each character in the input...
  _eu_el=   e#   Make an upper case and a lower case copy and check if they are equal.
  {         e#   If they aren't... (i.e. if this is a letter)
    Pmr     e#     Generate a uniformly random value in [0,π).
    mc      e#     Take the cosine.
    1.mr    e#     Generate a uniformly random value in [0,1).
    ml      e#     Take the natural logarithm.
    -50*    e#     Multiply by -50.
    mq*     e#     Take the square root and multiply by the cosine.
    A+      e#     Add 10.
    mo      e#     Round to nearest integer.
    {       e#     That many times...
      48mr  e#       Generate a uniformly random integer in [0,47].
      '̀+    e#       Add it to the first combining mark.
    }*
  }|
}/
```

This means we just dump all the characters and combining marks on the stack in the correct order, where they are printed automatically at the end of the program.

Comment: Little nitpick, your code uses  ̀, which is `&#768;`, or [codepoint U+0300, combining grave accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0300/index.htm). This requires two bytes in UTF-8: `0xCC 0x80`. Your code has 47 characters, but 48 bytes. Other than that, brilliant piece of work!

Comment: @Abel Thanks but I think you miscounted the characters: [it's 46 characters and 47 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#q%7B%5feu%5fel%3D%7BPmrmc1.mrml-50%2amq%2aA%2Bmo%7B48mr%27%CC%80%2B%7D%2a%7D%7C%7D%2F).

Comment: Oh darn, you are right! I checked column number in my editor, it showed 48, but it starts at +1...

Comment: I really like this answer. But please be aware that you cannot determine whether something is a letter merely by checking whether it doesn’t change case between that character’s uppercase mapping and its lowercase mapping. Unicode 6.1 has 12,167 letters whose lc and uc mappings are the same, 7,320 in the BMP alone. Example include:   ª º ĸ ƺ ȡ ȷ ȹ ɡ ɢ ɤ ɪ ɷ ɼ ɾ ʁ ʤ, plus lots of others.

Comment: @tchrist "Input is a single line string that contains only characters between ASCII 32 (space) and ASCII 126 (tilde)." ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Gorsh, that's just plain lazy! :) Why use Unicode at all then? :(  The point stands that you cannot actually use this for determining letterness in the real world. Just kidding: I’ll try to read more carefully next time. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like CJam needs a normal distribution function :)

Answer (score 14):

### Python3, <s>162</s> 156 bytes

```
from random import*
q=lambda z:''.join([v,v+''.join(choice(list(map(chr,range(768,815))))for i in range(int(normalvariate(10,5))))][v.isalpha()]for v in z)
```

Possible usage:

```
print(q(u"Programming Puzzles and Code Golf"))
```

I import random, generate a string of all combining characters, return a random subset of combining characters according to mean 10, stddev 5 normal distribution and append to each alpha letter in then string, then join the results.

Test input:

```
Programming Puzzles and Code Golf
```

Test Output:

> P̡̣̝̬̞̃̏̋r̫̤̒̇̋̂̉̔̂̕ó̘̫̔g̭̤̝̖̅̏̍̆̇̍ȑ̮̭̃̎̒̄̅̊̚ḁ̉̅̎̑m̧̠̤̎̒̅̂̓̒m̨̮̏̐̓̐̇ī̘̌́̄̆̋̏̉̇ń̝̀̑̔̅̏́̑̕g̢̞̬̥̜̩̖̎̍́ P̨̞̮̭̂̄̄ử̝̔̍̋̀̕zž̧̥́l̩̫̣̉̊̍̋̐̊̌ĕ̡̛̤̖̤̄̅̈̚s̨̨̞̝ ą̙̦̖̄̓̊̌̉̌n̢̙̜̪̤̣̪̔d̘̙̠̝̫̭̜̑̔̕ C̢̛̝̦̬̝̈̄̏̏ȏ̡̇̓̐̎̆̉̌̄d̗̝̞̤̟̭̓̐̈̕ė̡̛̜̥̥̠̟̦̌ G̖̟̘̅̄̈́̚o̧̗̬̗̥̞̙̐̌̊l̢̞̖̟̑̇f̢̛̩̀̒̃̌̈

Comment: I applied all the suggestions from @FryAmTheEggman suggestions which cut it down to about 161 bytes.

Comment: This zalgoifies non-alphabetic characters

Comment: [This](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#from%20random%20import%2a%0Aq%3Dlambda%20z%3Au%27%27.join%28%5Bv%2Bu%27%27.join%28choice%28u%27%27.join%28map%28chr%2Crange%28768%2C815%29%29%29%29for%20i%20in%20range%28int%28normalvariate%2810%2C5%29%29%29%29%2Cv%5D%5Bv.isalpha%28%29-1%5Dfor%20v%20in%20z%29) should fix the non-alpha problem.

Comment: Thanks @FryAmTheEggman, I somehow misread the discription to say space and tilde were the only non-ascii characters in the input.  But now I see that it means any characters.  I used your hint, but took away one character by switching the order.

Comment: You can replace the `join` around the `map` with a call to `list`. I feel like there should be a better way to do that... Anyway, are the `u` prefixes necessary? When I run it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/BH1M/1) without them it seems to work ok? Maybe strings get auto-promoted to unicode? Haven't fiddled much with that before.

Comment: The `u` prefix is not needed in python 3. Unless you're mixing byte strings with Unicode ones.

Comment: Applying FryAmTheEggman and Kevin Brown's suggestions... for another 6 bytes off.

Comment: Typo in the quoted result, presumably accidental.

Answer (score 13):

## MATLAB, 89 bytes

Credits go out to DankMemes, but as I am not able to comment yet I'm forced to place my improvements w.r.t. his MATLAB submission in a separate answer.

```
function o=z(a),o=[];for c=a,o=[o,c,randi(49,[1,isletter(c)*fix(normrnd(5,10))])+767];end
```

Slightly more golfed by replacing the newlines with commas and semicolons (which also suppresses the intermediate outcomes from the loop).

- *9 bytes* can be won by replacing **isstrprop(c,'alpha')** with **isletter(c)**.
- We don't need the dots in front of * and +, as we multiply with a scalar. That's another *2 bytes*.
- **fix** instead of **floor** for *2 bytes*. It does give a slight bias towards 0 though, so alternatively **ceil** can be used to gain *1 byte*.
- I changed the random character pick to work with random integers between 1 and 49 to reduce the amount of operations and save some additional bytes.

Using it with

```
z('Simple check for proper functionality results in this beautiful text!')
```

Results in

> Ś̜̬̭̃̑̓́̃i̩̰̗̙̫̜̇̀̑mplë̥̟̣̩̙̗̐̌̇ cḧ̢̛̰̝̣̝̋̋̑eç̛̞̖̖̰̰̝̭̞̜̝̥̋̎̇̄̂̆̆̔̎̊k̢̟̠̞̈̌̂ for̢̡̫̥̩ ṗ̝̥̗̬̯̯̝̍̑̈̊rop̡̡̨̢̝̫̤̠̫̠̏̎̄́̒ė̦̋̕ŕ̦̣̇̊ f̧̜̦̏̏̉̇unc̨̢̗̟̙̩̝̠̄̈̋̑̏̎̄̇̌̒́̇̚ti̝ỏ̧̯̰̥̣̜̎̓̀̊̔̒̉̔̑̑̔̋̚n̡̘̠̮̤̖̥̤̂̔̇̇al̩̫̇̇̔it̫̮̔̎̕y̡̰̰̦̔̇̏̎̋ r̛̙̯̉ĕ̬̟̉̓̌s̛̝̝̭ul̨̧̧̛̙̤̥̜̟̞̔̓̓̊̀̂t̡̠́̓̀̉̎̒̈̚ş̗̠̋̍̏̌̎̕ ǐ̛̗̭̪̤̃̏̍̎̈̓̐̚n̞̮̞̬̝̭̎̔̍ th̢̧̛̬̬̖̠̗̮̰̠̖̖̠̞̦̞̎̄̓̎̇̆̚̕is̟̬̍̂̎ bea̭̗̝ṳ̝̞̠̦̣̤̦̅̂̒̄̒̔̉̏tỉ̪̩̅̓̂f̢̝̰̬̤̰̊̊̉̎̕̕u̡̝̇l tex̰̤̥̍̕t̡̝̥̣̟̩̟̉̂̆̋̈̈̈̍̔!

Comment: Instead of using `normrnd`, you can save 3 bytes by using `10+5*randn`. Note that no parentheses are required to call `randn`.

Comment: I accidently downvoted this, how can I retract my vote that is now "locked in"?

Comment: @feersum Funny that you mention it. I actually tried it, but the distribution for a large number of repeats didnt' seem right to me. Try it for like 1e+6 values and see for yourself.

Comment: @ReutSharabani This is possible if someone edits the post. All votes are unlocked afterwards.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu thanks, I thought there was some way... Sorry for the accidental downvote :-) I was on mobile and probably clicked it there.

Answer (score 11):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>199</s> 196 bytes

Uses a [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) for the normal distribution (which ends up taking a lot of space, unfortunately. JS is not the best language when it comes to normal distributions)

```
i=>i.split``.map(e=>e.match(/[a-z]/i)?e+Array((i=~~((M=Math).sqrt(-50*M.log((R=M.random)()||.1))*M.cos(M.PI*R()||.1)+10))<0?0:i).fill().map(f=>String.fromCharCode(~~(R()*48+768))).join``:e).join``
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Leq5kyf9/3/)

Edit: I made a mistake and had to add one byte. This should now zalgoify capital letters as well as lowercase ones.

Edit 2: Simplified the transform as in Martin Buttner's answer.

Comment: You can shave 3 bytes by using a `with` statement: `with(Math){i=>i.split``.map(e=>e.match(/[a-z]/i)?e+Array((i=~~(sqrt(-50*M.log((R=random)()||.1))*cos(PI*R()||.1)+10))<0?0:i).fill().map(f=>String.fromCharCode(~~(R()*48+768))).join``:e).join``}`

Answer (score 11):

## Perl, <s>81</s> 79<sup><sup>(?)</sup></sup> bytes

Gee, you guys are all using variables!  Who needs variables? :)

Here’s the simple code, which is just 79 bytes, most of it taken up by silly identifiers<sup><sup>(but not variables :)</sup></sup>:

```
use Math::Random;s/\pL\K/(x x random_normal 1,10,5)=~s,.,chr 768+rand 48,reg/eg
```

Which, written more normally without compression, might be:

```
use Math::Random;
s{ 
    \pL         # find a Letter
    \K          # and Keep it, so the insertion point is right afterwards
}{
    # make a string of x's and replace each with a random combining character
    ("x" x random_normal(1,10,5)) =~ s{
            .  # take any character, including our x
        }{
            chr( int(768 + rand(48)) );
    }xreg;
}xeg;
```

### How It Works

1. Load the [Math::Random](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Random) module, importing the *random_normal* function.
2. For each letter of the input:

   1. Get 1 random real number from a normal distribution whose mean is 10 and whose standard deviation is 5.
   2. Create a string containing as many *x*’s as the integer truncation of that random normal real number.
   3. For each of those  *x*’s:

      1. Generate an evenly distributed random real number in the range [768, 768+48).
      2. Derive the character whose code point is the integer truncation of that random number.
      3. Replace the current *x* with that character.
   4. Place the resulting string of combining characters after that letter.

### How to Count?

But I’m not quite sure how to count it because I’m not clear on the output requirements and the function requirements and how these impact counting.

### File Execution

The solution above transforms its input and leaves the result where it is using the normal input space as with *sed*. If you want it printed, you would need to add a `-p` switch.

So for example, if you put that in a file named *zalgo* then you could test it this way:

```
echo These are not the zebras you are looking for. |
perl -p zalgo
```

which produces

> ## T̛̝̠̟̙̭̗̮̘̠̪̖̤̍́̇ĥ̫̞̥̙̞̈̈e̢̨̛̟̥̥̫̐̒̄s̛̮̊̒̆́ę̨̛̪̗̝̙̥̘̯̈̃̏̑̄̆̍ à̢̨̖̫̟̮̂̍̒̍̓ř̛̜̌̎̅ȩ̛̗̣̗̬̒̉̄̇̉ n̥̟̪̪̙̞̠̝̪̄̓̅̈̎ȏ̧̭̭̫̤̥̒̉ţ̛̛̜̅̔̏̍̆̓̊̔̍̍̕ t̝̬̜̫̦̜̭̄̀̂̈̎ȟ̛̗̭̌̏̐̍̀̚ē̯̬̙̖̘̒̕ z̡̨̛̯̠̥̪̣̤̟̐̍̀̉ë̬̫̪̟̟̔̚b̗̝̣̎́̚r̞̟̋ã̢̛̪̪̗̝̞̝̃̄̄s̡̢̧̛̙̖̙̘̊̐́̀̎̚ ÿ̢̪̥̤̮̫̏̇̌̆o̡̜̝̓ŭ̜̖̦̥̦̞̑̏ á̡̤̫̞̟̥̘̒̔̋̑̐r̛̛̮̥̘̫̅ȩ̦̗̞̯̮̄́̂̈ ľ̠̉̈̀̒̚ò̖̘̖̉̋̀̊̔̏̇̕o̡̦̦̜̫̫̬̅̇́̌̏̚k̡̪̔̄̉̍̄̋̂̊ȉ̢̨̙̭̥̫̟̉̑́̏̌̚̚n̜̣̎̄̄̐̈̋g̖̞̭̘̜̞̑̂̃̅̅ f̡̧̡̛̤̓̀̏̚o̓ṙ.

I’ll revise the byte count once I learn how you’d like this to be counted.

---

### Zalgotic Beowulf

If might be better to test this on something with more interesting letters so show that it doesn’t get stuck on some 1960s notion of what letters are.  For example, it should be well-behaved on stuff like *æþelingas*. So given this text with the three first lines of *Beowulf*:

> Hwæt, we gar-dena in geardagum,
>  
>   þeodcyninga þrym gefrunon,
>   hu ða æþelingas ellen fremedon!

Here’s how to make a zalgotic Beowulf:

```
perl -p zalgo beowulf
```

Which emits:

> H̝̙̓̒w̢̩̞̫̠̖̍̅̉̚̕̚æ̛̖̭̭̝̊̄̒t̢̬̩̒̑̑̇̔, w̨̢̢̘̥̎̆̑̉̐̇̃́̃̌ę̛̛̩̥̩̣̗̮̜̗̋̂̋̒̒̑̆̆̑̒̀ g̗̦̟̯̑ā̖̦̮̀̐̏̓r̢̫̄̈̊̉-d̨̗̪̜̃́̂̅̕ḙ̡̨̠̣̠̣̎̉̄̊̐̒̂̏̓̔n̟̤̫̓̄̉̓̔ą̗̪̃̈̔ i̡̤̤̣̠̮̍̚n̨̟̝̥̊̈̌̀̏̂̌̍ g̡̛̜̘̮̈̋̈̂̒̓̕e̢̞̤̐̒a̢̨̪̟̟̘̦̗̬̓̐̉̎́̏̓r̡̫̙̐̑̉ḋ̛̖̮̫̜̫̒ą̢̣̮̦̪̙̮̙̠̏̂̎̄̉́̅̚g̛̭̣̩̜̙̓̑̎̊̑̏̏u̡̢̞m̡̫̝̞̗̟̞̈̉̆̋̒, 
>   þ̢̧̛̩̟̬̘̣̟̦̣̃̊̋̌̎ḙ̭̖̋̊́̎ọd̪̙̉c̝̭̩̦̠̓̅̅̍̐ỷ̖̞̥̦̐̍̏̄́n̬̥̥̣̗̂̀̄̕ĩ̡̡̗̞̩̗̋̒̆̏ṅ̢̢̫̬̝̑̉̌̈̌̐ĝ̥̭̬̤̇̂̅̎̂̅́̊̇ā̫̦̥̗̙̙́̀̕ þ̢̙̥̝̬̖̣̦̬̗̗̎̌̓̄̐̑r̡̢̨̯̬̮̝̮̜̩̃̉̅̐̀̑̓̐̉̈y̖̜̫̠̜̐̕m̧̟̜̣̘ g̢̧̪̗̫̘̖̃̍̓̑e̡̯̓f̛̬̥̔̌̒ř̨̜̙̠̥̒́̋ú̗̘̊̆̆̄̕̕n̢̛̜̫̍̐̐̋̉o̤̘̬̜̥̖̜̫̎̋̔̏̍̀̋̉n̨̧̮̆̑̅̇, 
>   h̨̬̪̝̭̀́̐̕̚̚ú̜̖̭̭̯̘̗̠̊̊̆̌̀̀̕̕̕̚ ð̦̦̤̠̬̖̏̉̑̓̆̍̒̋̚̕ẳ̧̫̦̚ æ̯̙̘̣̯̋̆̑̑̀̅þ̢̝̣̯́̆̇̈̐̊̅̈ệ̗̙̣̙̪l̢̧̝̗̦̖̟̔̄̐̄̊̚i̡̬̝̘̜̍̉̏̑̍̊̐̋̔̉ņ̥̩̣̋̐̊̇̔̎̉̋̓ģ̝̬̯̪̥̞̪̃̅à̧̨̤̫̖̊̅̓̄̑̏̊̋̚̚s̨̡̥̭̞̙̎̓ ê̜̆̊̆́l̘̪̟̙̙̝̎̀́̂ľ̢̛̬̥̗̋̀̐̅̎̔̔̄̉ẽ̡̨̤̬̭̦̞̤̯̬̍̀̋̚ň̢̨̖̘̣̖̝̞̙̍̀̆̄̂̕ f̩̘̦̦̜̦̞̑̏̄̋r̘̓ẹ̤̠̟̀̅̔m̢̪̮̙̗̆̉̒̚̕̚e̎d̬̘̓̒̈̆̓̒̄̑̚ò̡̝̥̮̯̝̜̯̜̘̞̑̐̌̇̓̐n̪̣̗̤̈̎́̆̊!

---

### All CLI, No Files

If you wanted to go all command line, you could inline it this way:

```
echo "This particularly rapid unintelligible patter isn’t generally heard and if it is, it doesn’t matter." |
perl -CS -MMath::Random -ple's/\pL\K/(x x random_normal 1,10,5)=~s,.,chr 768+rand 48,reg/eg'
```

and generate this from it:

> ## T̢̜̪̜̬̥̝̂̉̆̈̏̏̒̂̋̊̕h̢̛̙̝̦̥̫̉̌̑̐̚į̧̧̪̀̉̌̐š̙̗̘̑̉̒̋̈̍̐̊ p̡̛̛̗̞̜̙̔́̊̊̊̆a̬̦̫̠̦̜̐̂̈́̅r̢̩̩̝̣̖̔̊̇̈t̢̘̫̪̜̄̍̏̌̄̚i̞̟̜̊̍̒́̄̂c̟̑̑̃̌̋ư̧̫̫̝̠̟̦̎̋̍̓l̛̥̞̖̟̩̈̋̈̍̍a̢̜̦̘̫̓̉̇̂̇̒̓̆ȓ̪̤ļ̬̫̟̣̬̬̆̃y̌ ŕ̩̞̟̖̝̬̟̪́̒̐̔ȧ̡̟̖̙̤̜́́̎̍̀̒̌̋p̪̤̦̜̒̉̈̌̌̆̇̉̚ỉ̧̡̟̪̔̔̀̈̅̆ḑ̖̣̐̆̍́̃ ṳ̩̗̫̦̦̗̤̅̃̒̊̆nį̧̢̫̪̦̩̞̞̎̉̅̇̆̔́̋̐̍ņ̡̧̛̩̘̪̪̪̎̈̕̕t̥̤̬̩̦̓̄̍̑̇̄e̡ĺ̢̠̓̂̇̅̐̚ľ̗̭̝̪̀̅̕í̤̬̥̙̭̠̊̅́̒ģ̩̬̣̃̐̆̇̓i̛̗̦̭̙̝̐̔̇̄̉̄̇bl̖̭̘̣̙̤̇̎̔̅̒̔̚e̘̤̖̞̎̎̅̍̕ p̧̢̡̟̠̜̬̩̃̀̆̃̆̍a̧̡̭̙̥̤̟̟̔̄̎̔̓̕t̖̦̎̊̏̉̕ţ̤̥̦̝̜̭̤̈̆̊̓̈̊̎̚ȇ̡̛̖̈̊̓̎̕r̟̫̍̒̅̈̈ i̧̘̪̠̟̗̙̭̍̇̄̊ş̛̩̖̦̬̞̣̤̘̫̓̊̆̈̌̓̐̎̕n̡̧̜̥̤̪̩̋̇’t̓̈̑̀̈̔̈̐̔̊̒ g̛̤̋̇̋ę̢̛̛̠̤̥̟̞̣̫̞̬̝̙̐́̂̂̍̕n̩̟̙̞̖̭̫̂̂̌̃̔̉̑ȩ̗̥̥̠̂̈̉̅r̪̫̩̂̀̄aḽ̢̜̖̝̌̇̓́̒̑ļ̢̧̫̦̥̬̤̑̎̒̒̓̑̚̚̕ỳ̛̥̖̭̍̐̃̑̍ h̖̬̠̠̝̜̝̪̗̒̊̊̋̄ȩ̛̞̭̪̜̤̟̘̣̅̆̃́̂̔a̛̝̕r̝̦̅̅̍̍̎̂̊ḑ̩̞̬̘̪̝̝̍̏̂̓̔̄̑̕ ą̡̧̬̞̝̟̍̓̉́̈̀ň̛̟̩̙̈d̡̜̥̣̦̫́̅̌̚ ĩ̖̜̔f̧̅̌ į̡̢̪̬̫̟̜̄̑̑̓̊̚̕̚t̪̘̦̩̐̄́̐ ỉ̥s̪̝̤̀̈̚, ǐ̪̭t̛̬̭̝̋̄̋̇̏̉̆̚̕̕ d̝̗̭̓̒̂o̡̝̙̒̅̒̏̉̚e̢̦̦̝̘̘̣̔̓ş̛̤̤̊̇̃̋̎ṅ̨̧̬̤̜̚’ţ̪̗̭̘̟̝̔̋̑̀̇̃̈ m̢̛̦̭̖̥̪̫̙̤̈̅̏̃̂̆̋̈̌̕ả̛̜̝̝̗̣̦̅̚t̫̤̜̘̒̅̅̚t̪̬̗̘̑́̔̓̏̅̉̆ȇ̡̦̘̣̘̭̖̞̥̄̔̑̆̂̃̀̀̍̇̉̚̕r̛̭̙̘̬̉̄̆̉̇̅́̕̕.

---

#### The Fine Print

<sub>To really make this work well, you may need to have something in your environment or on the command line or in the file to say this is Unicode throughout. That might be `-CS` or `-CSD`, or `PERL_UNICODE=S` or `PERL_UNICODE=SD` depending on which way you’re going at it. However, because the problem says we don’t actually have to print anything, and that the input is mere ASCII, these are not needed for the small specific case given in the problem description.</sub>

Comment: You should probably call this "Bash/Perl", because it really won't work in all command lines.

Comment: @TheDoctor That doesn't make much sense to me. The Perl code is the same; how you manage to run it is up to you.

Answer (score 7):

## Groovy, <strike>201</strike> <strike>196</strike> <strike>182</strike> <strike>174</strike> <strike>170</strike> <strike>154</strike> <strike>146</strike> <strike>130</strike> <strike>129</strike> 124 bytes

My first golf, not really aiming to win here but figured I'd give it a shot anyway.

Run it as `groovy zalgo.groovy 'input'`

```
o='';r=new Random();args[0].chars.any{o+=it;if(it.letter)(r.nextGaussian()*5+10).times{o+=(char)(768+r.nextInt(48))}}print o
```

Ungolfed ([with syntax highlighting](https://gist.github.com/unascribed/500f6acaed7d01657abd)):

```
// By making this a Groovy script, the weight of
// a full Java-like class definition can be avoided
////
// Originally, this part of the answer used the 'def'
// keyword to infer the type of the variable, but it
// turns out you can define a variable in Groovy
// without any type at all.
buffer = '';
rand = new Random();
// There used to be a for loop here using def, but now it's a
// .any closure. .any saves a byte over .each.
////
// Groovy automatically defines an args variable for
// scripts, which we use here.
args[0].chars.any {
    // As in Java, += works on a String. Previous versions of the
    // answer used a StringBuffer, but a String works just as well.
    buffer += it;
    // Another Groovy extension; we can use the primitive char like
    // a Character object, and use .letter instead of .isLetter()
    if (it.letter)
        // Since Gaussian is already a normal distribution with mean 0
        // stddev 1, we can fix that with a quick multiply and add.
        ((rand.nextGaussian() * 5) + 10).times {
            // I use the literal number '768' here, as it's the same size
            // as a Java char literal, and Groovy doesn't have char literals.
            buffer += (char)(768+rand.nextInt(48));
        }
}
// Finally, we can take a quick shortcut here by using the
// parentheses-less syntax for print in Groovy. Using print
// instead of println saves a whole two bytes!
print buffer
```

Example output:

> P̊r̡̜̋̎̎̆ȍ̧̨̖̣̖̠̪̬̘̂̚g̩̯̗̈̃̆r̡̮̭̬̙̟̟̭̗̅̐̀̑̕ą̢̛̜̗̗̩̂̓̂̎̕m̝̬̊̂̒̐̕m̤̠̪̣̍̓̍̂̍̚į̫̣̞̝̬̪̘̟̎̅̒n̛̬̦̗g̝̦̏̇̏̀̆̓ P̨̨̡̉́̓̒̕ų̠̤̪̬̘̪̪̤̪̏̀̎z̛̜̀̒̐̕ž̛̙̮̩̔̌̉̉̎̍́̑l̨̡̤̗̮̜̣̬̩̜̜̭̦̈̒̊̃̊̌̉ȩ̘̬̖̞̗̦̘̪̬̇̅̅̈s̒̄́̌̎ & Ĉ̢̣̜̗̟̤̌̒ơ̡̜̪̖̫̂̉̍̆̐̊̇̔̍̕̚d̛̛̦̫̫̯̥̯̭̍̋̔̆̂̕ê̫̪̆̍̒̄ G̙̪̅ȏ̢̥̖̘̦̟̜̪̈̔̌̑l̯̘̞̅f̬̗

Answer (score 6):

### Moonscript - <strike>118 117 112 110 105</strike> 96 bytes

<strike>This needs to be saved as Latin 1, but generates utf-8.</strike> It uses the central limit theorem to approximate the normal distribution. `math.random!` returns a number with a uniform distribution 0 to 1, which has a mean of 0.5 and a standard deviation of 1/sqrt(12). If we add 300 samples, we get a number with a mean of 150 and a standard deviation of 5, with an approximately normal distribution. We subtract 140, and the distribution now has the correct mean.

In utf-8, the character codes U+300 to U+32F are encoded as 11001100:10000000 to 11001100:10101111. So it is the byte 204 followed by a random byte 128 to 175.

```
r=math.random
=>@gsub '%a',(b=-140)=>
 b=b+r!for _=1,300
 @=@..@.char(204,127+r 48)for _=1,b
 @
```

This is a code block which returns an anonymous function taking one argument, the string, and returning the zalgo-fied version. Assuming this is saved in zalgo.moon, a full program that uses this would be:

```
print require'zalgo' io.read!
```

Edit:

- Turns out it's cheaper to use char code 204 instead of an embedded Latin 1 character.
- Can access string.char using a.char
- Switch to command line args, rather than stdin.
- use method for implicit parameter @.
- Switch to a function that returns a value

Answer (score 6):

## MATLAB, 106 bytes

I thought I'd submit another answer from a language which actually has a built in normal distribution function. I don't think I've ever tried MATLAB before so this may not be the most golfed it can be.

```
function o=z(a)
o=[]
for c=a
o=[o c floor(rand(1,floor(normrnd(5,10)*isstrprop(c,'alpha'))).*48.+768)]
end
```

Answer (score 5):

### AutoIt - (sad) 219 bytes

```
dim $r=random,$f
for $u in stringsplit($i,"",3)
do
dim $a=2*$r()-1,$b=$a^2+(2*$r()-1)^2
until $b<1
$f&=$u
for $m=1 to $a*sqrt(-2*(log($b)/$b))*5+10
$f&=stringregexp($u,"\p{L}")?chrw($r(768,815)):""
next
next
clipput($f)
```

What's really bloating up the code is the distribution calculation. I cheated a bit by writing the output directly to the clipboard, because `clipput` is the shortest output function in AutoIt. The RegEx `\p{L}` matches all letters.

---

You have to supply the input using a global variable `$i`:

```
$i = "A study in scarlet."
```

yields

> Ą̣̘̤̪̜̮̎̊ s̭̫t̡̢̢̡̢̩̝̙̍̏̂̇̎̍̂̈ǖ̮̮̭̬̋̕ḑ̦̗̟̄̀̒̌̂̕y̨̧̙̪̩̎̀̓̋ į̣̦̥̮̔̈̃̅̐̌n̗̜̑ s̘̦̞̘̗̠̣̤̏̊̐c̨̡̛̭̝̬̭̜̟̥̝̮̍̄̊̎̔á̡̬̤̠̦̠̗̟̆̍̄̈̕r̛̤̥̬̠̋̍̒̚ļ̨̞̫̤̆̊̋̑ë̟̪̝̞̑̌̎̆̓̇̇̀̚̕t̢̖̟̞̟̘̮̅̎̂̐.

Comment: +1 for autoit, I don't think I've ever seen it here before.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, <s>190</s> <s>169</s> 136 bytes

```
function q(z){var o="",r=Math.random;for(var v in z){o+=z[v];for(var k=0;k<r()*100;k+=r()*10){o+=String.fromCharCode(768+~~k)}}return o}
```

usage :

```
var d=q("There is snow on the ground \
And the valleys are cold \
And a midnight profound \
Blackly squats o'er the wold; \
But a light on the hilltops half-seen hints of feastings un-hallowed and old. \
")
```

output :

...

> T̡̗̙̀̅̎h̀è̇̋r̖̀̄̉̍̔̕è̀̅̉̏ ̀ì̘̟̥̫̱̀̇̐s̖̟̦̀̀̀̉̊̍
>   ̗̀̇̉̎̕s̗̀̃̈̊̑ǹ́̈̍̏̐ò̅̈̎ẁ̃̅̋ ̀̉ò̜̟̦̬́̄̌̓ǹ̘̀̉̌̍̒
>   ̛̝̀̈̒t̀̀̀h̘̀̈̐è̇̊̋̍̐ ̙̝̥̪̮̱̀̂̋̔g̗̀̉̒r̖̀̉̑ò̅̋̎̏̓̓ù̙̈̋̑ǹ̄d̖̀̉̏̑̔
>   ̀̆̊̍̕ ̀́̆̍ ̛̀̂̂̆̍̏̕ ̀̉̎ ̀̈̌̍̒À̖̜̠̅̍̏ǹ̀d̀́
>   ̀t̢̙̀̆̎̐̓h̜̤̤̀̈̉̊̊̏̓è̢̘̣̈̋̎̓
>   ̀̂̄̅̇̍̎v̗̙̀́̄̋̍̓̓̔̚à̛́̅̋̎̓̚l̀̂̊l̀̀̆̎̕è̗̈̑̕ỳ̃̊̍s̀̀̅̉̑
>   ̀̀̂̈à̈̊̌̎̑̒r̢̢̘̤̀̂̃̃̋̑̓è̖̗̇̉̏ ̀̈̈̍̎̑c̀̃̈̏ò̄l̀̆̍d̀̅̈̉ ̀̉̒̓
>   ̷̡̨̙̥̬̮̰̀̄̍̒̿̓͌̕ ̛̀̉̌̒ ̀̃ ̀́̈̊̐̑À̈̊̏̏̑ǹ̂̌̎d̖̀̉̑̕ ̙̀̃̆̋̔à
>   ̖̀̀̄̆̌̍̕m̛̖̀̃̄̇̇̍ì̀̄̅̆̋̕d̀̈̊̏̕ǹ̀́̇̉ì́̊̎̕g̘̘̀̇̍̑h̗̟̟̀̅̎t̜̞̣̀̀̃̋̍̏̒
>   ̛̖̀̇̍p̖̟̥̀̈̍̓̚r̛̠̀̅̍̍̕ò̢̖̜̃̄̎̎̓̓f̘̙̜̀̂̇̊̒ò̙̅̉̐̕̚ù̡̖̙́̂̈̉̋̔̔ǹ́̇d̀̂̇̇̉
>   ̘̘̀̄̇̑ ̨̖̖̗̣̀̄̆̊̏̑̑̚ ̀̉̒ ̀̀̅̈̋̑
>   ̢̗̙̀̀́̅̍̎B̀̆̋l̤̫̀̀̇̍̔̚̚à̂̃̋c̀̄̄k̜̥̪̀̄̇̋̎̓̓l̀̂̉̊̐ỳ̃
>   ̖̘̀̉̍̎̐s̀̆̇̊̑q̀́̂̄̄̇̍ùà̈̎̑t̀̂̅̈s̀̀̀́̃̅̅̍
>   ̛̀́̂̇̉̌̓̔ò̅̅̇̇'̀́̄̇è̄r̡̛̀̀̈̈̒ ̀́̉t̀̀̂̊h̀̂̆è̢̂̋̔̚
>   ̀̀́̄ẁ̞̦̫̰̀̇̌̍̕ò̂̃̄l̝̀̇̎̏̒̒̕̚d̘̜̜̞̥̀̃̉̐;̡̙̤̪̬̀̇̋̑ ̘̙̠̀̆̎̚ ̀̅̉̓ ̖̀̃̌
>   ̖̙̀́̄̅̉̒ ̀B̀̈̐̔ừ̘̆̎̏̑t̘̟̀̃̉̊̍̏ ̀̉̋à́̈̋̐
>   ̀̉̊̒̒̔l̀̀̇̊̍̓̚ì̃g̀̈̐h̨̖̟̮̀̂̆̋̔t̀̇̌̍ ̀̇ǫ̗̠̠̀̆̈̉̑ǹ̇̌̍
>   ̙̣̀̀́̉̏̒t̀̀h̗̜̀̃̊̊̌̎è̙́̈̋̍̔
>   ̀̂h̗̀̂̇̈̏ì̙̝̣̉̑̓̓l̗̜̀̃̃̇̑l̞̀̈̏̑̕t̙̟̀̅̍̎̕̚ò̂̄p̀̂̋̍s̀̄̇̐
>   ̖̀̄̋̍h̗̀̅̋̐̓à̶̢̧̝̮̈̏̕l̀̂̊f̀̀̇̇-̀̄̄̉̓s̀̂̇̍è̘̈̏è̖̟̤̥̩̰̇̏ǹ̇̋̏
>   ̀̇̋̐̕h̀̉̏ì́̃̈̈ǹ̅̏̓t̀̇̈s̀̄̌ ̀̃̇̊̒ò̖̖̃̋̋̏f̛̀́̅̉̑
>   ̀́̃̈f̀̅è́̅̉à̃̅̌̓s̛̗̣̤̀́̃̄̌̎̑t̀̆̉ì̞̤̭̃̈̑̚ǹ̗̟̦̂̂̅̆̊̊̊̏g̗̀̅̊̓̓s̀̂
>   ̀̄̉̑̓̔ù̅̋ǹ́̊̎̒-̀́̄̈h̀́́̊̓̔à̀̈̊l̛̀̄̌̎̔l̢̛̖̣̀̉̋̕ò̆̊ẁ̉̐̚è̆̌̍d̜̥̦̭̀̀̂̈̑̔̕
>   ̀̇̍̓à̈̊ǹ̗́̆̋̑̔̕ḍ̴̛̪̬̀̅̊̌̑ ̨̙̜̤̭̀̀́̈̎̏ò̈l̀̈̎̏̐d̢̝̬̀̂̃̋̌̔.̨̝̝̤̪̀̅̇̊̓
>   ̀̈̌̐̓̕ ̛̗̤̮̮̰̀̃̉̊̏̐̒ ̀̄̇̏ ̀̉̐ ̀́̅̇̎

Comment: I don't think you're using the required normal distribution. It looks more like a uniform distribution between 0 and 100 (i.e. mean 50).

Comment: argh, you're right

Comment: You also zalgoify punctuation, which is disallowed in the OP

Comment: why not use for `String.fromCharCode(768+~~k)` this: `String.fromCharCode(768|k)`?

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 73 bytes

```perl
s!\w\K!$x=-140;$x+=rand for 1..300;(x x $x) =~ s/x/chr 768+rand 48/ger!ge
```

Input is taken as newline-separated strings.

If you want to ignore the warnings printed to STDERR, use the `-C7` command-line flag.

This uses the same approximation for a normal distribution as the Moonscript solution.

Comment: I've cleaned up the formatting a bit. We prefer having the code be the first code block of the answer, not the invocation.

Comment: Since nobody said it yet, welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 223 bytes

```hs
import System.Random
import Data.Char
a!b=round$10+sqrt(-50*log a)*cos(2*pi*b::Double)
r=randomIO
m=mapM
z s=concat.zipWith(\c r->c:[x|x<-r,isAlpha c])s<$>(m(\_->(!)<$>r<*>r)s>>=m(\x->m(\_->randomRIO('\768','\815'))[1..x]))
```

`(!)` does a Box-Muller transform on a pair of numbers, z maps each letter into random normally distributed number `x`, which is then mapped into the range `[1..x]`, in which all numbers are replaced by a uniformly random punctuation. The original characters are then appended to these lists.

Sample output:

[T̢̨̮̝̘̖̗̣̟̝̞̘́̔̇̅̌̐̐̋̕ŗ̦̘̬̄y̩̦̯̞̍̂̑ ï̛̘̣̟̭̮̩̄̍̑̂̅̚t ȯ̖̤̞̎̓̔̏̕̕̚ń̢̦̖̟̠̜̯̒̀̏̑̕ļ̨̛̫̟̝̎̇̃̍̑̊̇ĩ̛̯̙̦̦̐̚n̮̪̮̞̞̈̄̔̀̚ȩ̨̜̟̬̟̫̩̦̌̂̆̋̏̄̏́!](https://tio.run/##LY1dS8MwGEbv@yvejUGTupZVmI7SBMTdDJTBJnixDkmzYoP5MkmhK/73WpyXz3ngnJb5r0bKcRTKGhfgePWhUdmB6YtR0T/cssCy55a5iM1q4kynL4t8dee/XUDpepVI8wkMJ9x4dJ9YkdRFsTVdLRscOeL@VLt9pIhi9jUawBNuNGchG4R9F6FFFQeXUl6c@p@@TN1S@CdpWwb8jH25oEih6iOlaIan4cqEOuwpJRPtU3r7bpHDbo/i6vFhEy/japOvY4xPeZb1Z4xHxYQGAgPM39wVRACjpdDNbA6TCmwXjsG96PEX)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>68</s> <s>63</s> 59 bytes

```perl6
{S:g/./{chrs roll max(0,-140+sum rand xx 300),768..815}$//}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxLC4JAAITv/oqhInr6oLIoOoTYA9IN7GK3pRYNVld2DRTpt9t6aRj4LjNfwSR326zGkO3bJtomlmk1z1QqSME5MlqN7NncWdpT9ckgaf5CVWFh2@PZ2t2Y5sZZfQeW9W13hmH0YSjaqUa9MmV4P1MhUTCZMVoyBaqFQYzjwfP/TJGIF3KBkOjqIIQqRYFOQPNJwrujZHpSQjLK8ThcTwSXCHcS1riffdxIGEPTI4Ef9ca79gc)

> t̤̣̜̉̌̂̇̍h̢̙̦̩̉ȇ̡̡̢̛̞̠̔̑̃̊̑̓ ̗̩̜̎̒̑i̛̭̤̘̒c̛̤̮̔́̑̃̔̅̐̑̚hǫ̘̣̩̣̙̙̆̎̂̉̋̊̕r̨̦̯̋̀̊̀ ̥̙̉̓̃̇̑p̢̨̛̯̗̥̞̞̘̬̪̗̠̖̅̅̉̃́̀̐̉e̖̋r̒̐m̧̖̪̉̐ẻä̪̞ţ̯̠̦̖̍̍̋̅̊̀̕ḙ̡̡̙̐̓̌̉̌ŝ̢̧̝̃̉̀ ̡̮̘̤̙̤̘̋̃̂̋̊̐̀̏̋̐̐̒ą̛̞̥̦̘̌̊̋̂̂̒̆l̢̛̛̮̘̜̦̝̫̮̪̟̭̖̜̅̑̂̍̑̉ḷ̨̞̜̤̠̣̪̥̋̀̇̊̊̍̈ ̢̢̤̜̬̫̊̇̑̐̇̑̒̕Ḿ̢̭̫̘̟̟̤̮́̃̎Y̧̬̖̜̆̀̍̍̐̒̉̒ ̡̗̔̎̆̆̀́̎F̬̯̯̏Â̡̛̝̭̎̂̉̑C̡̦̄̑̓Ę̛̭̞̤̂̓̔̃̎̓̏ ̛̪̬̯̘́̐̚MÝ̛̝̫̥̖̓̏̑̀ ̘̤̄́̍F̬̯̠̩̞̊̃̓̔̕Ă̙̥̞̤̕C̪̓̆E̡̟̝̭̦̮̎̒̅́ ̭̈̋ḣ̢̛̫̗̩̩̣̭̋̎̐̃̄̈̉̓ ̦̘̖̃̉̔̂̆̃̍̅̕g̡̧̢̜̬̪̞̟̒̇̊́̃̋̚ǭ̫̣̩̙̆̏̏̌̑̀̕d̟̮̠̬̙̗̥̪̭̜̐̑̊̔̕̕ ̨̙̠̟̠̯̆̑̅̒̔ṋ̛̘̜̞̦̈̋̋̍̋̈ơ̡̧̗̟̟̩̙̔̏̀̈̀̇̇̆̎̕ ̨̛̦̎̀̕N̛̄̋Ò̢̡̙̦̓̑̒̂̆́ ̧̗̮̠̗̮̯̆̉̑̅N̛̤̤̒O̧̤̯̯̦̥̒̍̏̃̇̊̕Ő̜̩̙̂̀̎̕Ọ̝̗̆̉Ơ̢̦̫̭̪̐̚̚ ̨̢̞̊̉̑̍̎̆̒N̡̞̭̙̏̏̓̄̚ ̠̖̫̦̗̓̉́s̤̄̋t̨̞̫̣̭̏̔̀ở̜̘̝̉ṗ̧̬̗̥̫̤̗̣̄̋̒̎́̒ ̯́̃̕ṭ̮̖̟̥̗̤́̊̋̇̎ḩ̞̜̗̪̊̂̏e̢̞̬̟̟̠̗̎̌̐̏̔̒ ̥̠̞̉̌́̈́̈̏̍ä̡̨̩̩̯̦̐̂n̢̟̫̖̯̞̗̙̙̊̋̐̍̚*̢̘́̒̉̎̚g̛̗̬̐̂́̇̉̆̀̚l̨̢̦̪̬̤̤̂̀̇̉̂̍̒̚ȩ̧̢̖̘̠̓̐́̈̌s̘̯̘̒̉̆̒̄̈̇̕ ̡̧̛̬̠̣̮̅ă̗̮̖̜̥̟̮̋̅̉̍̅̕r̢̢̢̤̩̙̩̋̑̓̍̆̍̕̚e̡̛̙̗̅̄̄̒́̚ ̡̖̫̞̖̖̟̣̭̅̐̄̑̊̃̉̎ǹ̗̟̤̄ö̪̏̎t̡̛̫̥̗̫̠̜̪̏̒ ̡̡̢̜̮̭̇̒̋̑̏̃̓̕r̡̗̬̯̪̝̮̂̊̒̏̔̉̀̚e̢̧̗̯̞̭̘̝̐̓̈̔̊̋̉å̖̣̔̋l̡̛̛̬̮̟̝̪̯̆̊ ̡̪̩̐̒Z̡̦̗̝̞̜̠̊̇̓̆AḶ̒̇̇̅̓̈̃̂Ğ̮̯̭̮̘̞̙̣̐̐̉̇Ő̡̠̞̄ ̢̟̖̪̋́́̔̚̚Į̪̗̭̖̊Ș̢̬̤̜̥̟̌̅ ̨̢̜̥̪̠̦̦̦̘̟̯̯̋̒̓̍̈̇̕T̢̉̆̌̊̎̈̕Ȍ̧̢̫̬̄̉̀̇̍̍̌̚̕Ņ̥̩̝̟̀̈̀̇̆̏̕y̛̟̫̠̭̫̗̫̮̬̥̥̭̗̓̏̑̋̍̇̐̔̋̐̅ ̝̥̘̫̪̖̫̅̂̌́̎̀̚̚̕Ṭ̌H̦̫̖̟̥̣̔̚̕Ę̢̬̮̩̣̙̇̅ ̨̧̝̭̩̟̈̂̈̃̓̓̚P̩̞̭̠̝̗̂̓̒̋̄Ợ̙̬̜̮̄̑̊̏̒N̘̤̆̏̇Y̨̫̪̜̖̯̒̎̋̌̍̈̄̊ ̧̣̠̣̜̌̄̇̋̄̊̉̏H̛̠̮̣̝̩̖̋̑̍E ̡̢̙̘̥̬̗̯̄̌̔̂̀̆̇̔̑C̪̣̮̋̇̎O̧̨̩̖̠̓̓̉̚̚̕M̛̛̙̘̟̪̙̘̩̝̖̉́̀̂̏̇Ẻ̡̛̛̘̯̜̆̀̓̓̒S

Uses the, ahem, 'binomial approximation' to the normal...

Text from [that bobince answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).