# HE COMETH NOT - a zalgo challenge

Tags: code-golf, string, unicode

Write a program or function that, given a string, will strip it of zalgo, if any exists.

### Zalgo

For this post, zalgo is defined as any character from the following Unicode ranges:

- Combining Diacritical Marks (0300–036F)
- Combining Diacritical Marks Extended (1AB0–1AFF)
- Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement (1DC0–1DFF)
- Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols (20D0–20FF)
- Combining Half Marks (FE20–FE2F)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character#Unicode_ranges

### Input

- May be passed via command line arguments, STDIN, or any other standard method of input supported by your language
- Will be a string that may or may not contain zalgo or other non-ASCII characters

### Output

Output should be a string that does not contain any zalgo.

### Test Cases

```
Input -> Output

HE̸͚ͦ ̓C͉Õ̗͕M͙͌͆E̋̃ͥT̠͕͌H̤̯͛ -> HE COMETH
C͉̊od̓e͔͝ ̆G̀̑ͧo͜l͔̯͊f͉͍ -> Code Golf
aaaͧͩa͕̰ȃ̘͕aa̚͢͝aa͗̿͢ -> aaaaaaaaa
ññ        -> ñn
⚡⃤       -> ⚡
```

### Scoring

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Is the string guaranteed to only contain ASCII and/or Zalgo? Or may it contain other unicode?

Comment: What about legitimate uses of those characters? Zalgo is pretty much only when those characters stack *with each other* in a way that was never intended.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem The input string may have other non-ASCII characters that must not be removed.

Comment: @Draco18s Any character in those Unicode ranges must be removed. Besides, I don't think golfing code that recognizes valid words with combining characters would be fun.

Comment: Is an encoding mandated or can any encoding be used?

Comment: @Doorknob Any encoding can be used but the definition of zalgo for this question still stands.

Comment: @totallyhuman I was thinking a more generic approach: only stripping if *more than one* occurs after a "standard" character. That is `a͕` is fine but `a͕̰` gets stripped to `a`. (Also now, thanks to the emoji detector, I want to put diacritics on emoji...̘͕̑ pfft, that looks silly)

Comment: @Draco18s That... might actually be a good idea but isn't it too late? Won't I be disrupting current progress?

Comment: No idea, honestly. I don't have a *good* idea of how things work around here. If this is deemed a good challenge, then my idea might make a good *second* challenge. But it's why we have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges).

Comment: I did put it in the sandbox but I got different questions there.

Comment: Then this question is probably fine as is. :)

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57601/8478)

Comment: You should add some test cases with non-ASCII output.

Comment: I would be grateful if somebody could do that as I am unable to do so for a while. (Preferably with the same length as the others because that just works. :P)

Answer (score 13):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 35 bytes

```
T`̀-ͯ᪰-᫿᷀-᷿⃐-⃿︠-︯
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#DcxBCoJQAIThvafwAu8UIbmJNh6gB9Uq8AqCIGgGiYplCRKVVAvd6c4LzBxCL@AR7K0@GH5mtjZwBOvh24jh1w@tI4a2H92zGN1@6koxdfU8mwbfzNHpiBf018iYwl0x5JWegSNcviyGKJmaeKLmTVMZAnuLeMeEhQ5vSQcRK5v3AxOVBHv6PGlSSlb8SHXYSFwUkVoKPpArM2X/Bw)

Simply removes all characters in the ranges given in the challenge from the input. The code is super unreadable of course, but the code is conceptually no different from something like `` T`0-9A-Za-z `` which would delete all alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Seems unbeatable enough to me.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I don't know, I think Jelly might be able to generate the code point ranges more efficiently than just listing the characters.

Comment: Actually I don't think it's able to.

Comment: I'm surprised there *is no* Jelly solution yet.

Comment: @icrieverytim [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142698/68942), and rip it's longer. I haven't figured out how to generate codepoints more effectively than this :P

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>73</s> 69 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to L3viathan.*

Not sure if participating in your own challenge is ok or not but... Stole the regex <s>and essentially the idea as well ><</s> straight from the JS and Retina answers.

```python
lambda s:re.sub('[̀-ͯ᪰-᫿᷀-᷿⃐-⃿︠-︯]','',s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#VY29asJQAIV3nyLbTcDrAxQ6FalLcXFrHa6YgKBGEt0DFwR/ChUVW1tBSltpO8ROZsvQ9ZyHiC/gI6R3Kjh98HE@jnd5l7dVp9FUVngRuKVw0LDFLSLJOPvay@w7zQ6RzA7pUT/Io05PyVaekrguikIUQ6fQ6vT8oG8Fbt4LWt2@7dmiUuYH10gszK84qmLFJfQNp3zisIwJNN9rnGLLZQVviPksHKfwX5sEY7@JucsFNxaG14ww487nS5sLMx97HPH@rFFKccdPZY72Co8GM2M2fMXacGWYnu1/f7rQxuR/)

Comment: Save 4 bytes by making that a normal import statement.

Comment: You forgot to update the byte count.

Comment: @xnor Huh? Seems right to me.

Comment: @totallyhuman My mistake, missed that those char are multibyte.

Comment: Well, it's fair to say that I stole the character range from the Retina answer. (With care though, since my editor wanted to remove the zalgo along with the `\``.)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 55 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/[̀-ͯ᪰-᫿᷀-᷿⃐-⃿︠-︯]/g,'')
```

```html
<textarea oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)></textarea><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 67 Bytes

shorter as the write out

```
<?=preg_replace("#[̀-ͯ᪰-᫿᷀-᷿⃐-⃿︠-︯]#u","",$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#JYxBS8JgHIfv@xTjtYOB@wRaO4QoQXTpphIv63U7yDYWnSIYDATNIFGxLEGikvIwu@RuO3j9/z7E/AJ@hPWHTg88PDwV03d8re0FSlpOsSHqVXxiRolOoxP0zmmKCUVnGOAZ3SrdU4SPCwxogUmd3inGiygJDqnvXdFIYYy5Tt0aQhpi6eG1gzFH/TZ6eNA5lVJiiS/J17WkJ8aQzRxvNGNOmSlXp9vfwGZuf1yKREteH8jAdg9vNfM4r5hHfqDsy0D5HWmpoig0KDQQZ99rI1ul2SY0sk26ix6NXZTuk4WxT@JW4YZvovS/KefKcjzRdJuuKGt3@R8)

## PHP, 115 Bytes

```php
<?=preg_replace("#[\u{300}-\u{36f}\u{1ab0}-\u{1aff}\u{1dc0}-\u{1dff}\u{20d0}-\u{20ff}\u{fe20}-\u{fe2f}]#u","",$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#LY0xS8NQEID3/Irw6lChQhrBpdUMUiyCuLg1Rc7kvWQoSYh0KgEhUGitQ2lLtVoQ0ZZO6iJuDl3vflM8eU7f3cfHXd1JwsRQcSrBC8st0WzQihb4beLkmAbnOKcZ5mc0ogfqN/AWc3q7oBE@06yJr/hOj6IiOMRh7ONE0pSWJvZP6AbHtI7pqUNTjoaKBnRncgoAtKYN8NUPwHvGmM2SXnDBnDN/uDrdfqUBc/sZYS7acL0DaRDt9gznqKg7h0kqg8tUJh3wZFmUWm63t29Z2d4fD1TGqMKV3qugtPC9f@FrYVu@FralhZK2FjyorF3q8n9R0Y9rhfTCWLiRG4makRW/)

## PHP, 35 Bytes

Valid for the given Testcases it removes all Marks

```
<?=preg_replace("#\pM#u","",$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#JczBSgJRFMbx/TzFcG1hYE@gNYsQRZA27ZqIw3SdWcjcy41WEQQDkmYLUbGmhAxLWlmbaNfC7flewheZDrT68x1@nFpgE@t1jNMUJeUT1azjHTn/@Dw@RP@IZ5hy1sYQj@jV@Y4zvB1jyC@YNnnJazypihLIA3POY40J5j73GrjhEVYGz11MBA066OPeF0pEWOGD5Osn8YNkJJc5XjmXzqS/olqbbxfvtQzfuljm5ivlTLrNF9tsqU7pYodcnO5eecFBUQv2rdPxmdO2S5Euq1Jo26VL4aryz6qFjhKjwjRMVdW7Lv4A)

Comment: @FelixDombek No it replaces only all Marks in the given ranges with nothing

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 37 bytes

```
r"[̀-ͯ᪰-᫿᷀-᷿⃐-⃿︠-︯]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#AVwAo///ciJbzIAtza/hqrAt4au/4beALeG3v@KDkC3ig7/vuKAt77ivXf//IkhFzabNmsy4IMyTQ82JT8yXzZXMg03NjM2ZzYZFzIvMg82lVM2MzKDNlUjMpMyvzZsgIg)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>127</s> 118 bytes

Just a straightforward answer for now, let's see how golfable it is.

```
lambda y:"".join(chr(x)for x in map(ord,y)if not(767<x<880or 6831<x<6912or 7615<x<7680or 8399<x<8448or 65055<x<65072))
```

Changelog:

- When will I ever learn that comprehensions are shorter than functional stuff (-9 bytes).

Comment: `0or` is not a thing, so you have to fix it or it will raise `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Did you actually test it? Doesn't throw an error for me on neither Python 3 nor 2.

Comment: Oh right. I was confused for a bit.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + coreutils, 41

```
tr -d '̀-ͯ᪰-᫿᷀-᷿⃐-⃿︠-︯'
```

Simply strips out characters in the given ranges.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#PY5PasJQEMb3OcXwaHH1rtCNSN2UbnqBh3mhQskrSZZdBAKC1oKi4p9WkNJW2i7izuxygfkOES/gEeJQsLP5wTc/vhkvcBElNk46JrbUDUm1W/jCigviSRP9W55jxtkNhlii1@JnzvB5hyFvMGvzB@d4VaRE5IHzeWIxxZq4d42Ux9g6vD1gKtIgQB8vYhpjsMW3kdKd4YVgLMka77wSzoWl8nznkcxj1A2TgNRlTPqKFF2c//zb2s69I/WfKXqqk4i0Tw1ONfLqZ6er37Lap7ral4dspA9ZeSw2@ljkjfpcIKdCW58A).

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 43 bytes

```apl
'[̀-ͯ᪰-᫿᷀-᷿⃐-⃿︠-︯]'⎕R''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#Fcw9qsJAGIXh/q4i3VSzCpFrI4LYicWAWolCVhAYCPiLokGNCir@oBbRynQpbM9ZRGYDLiFOqvfw8fBlrvGnog5PMkrvT5k@kvTtyfSdGD2VRiffeC@/cdQQZhJUhcgyV5SKvDBE7GBeYL@CJQPoMkdc0y9iCM1zjSPsGZRwQsSN@HOFlRj0mpi3uODOgf9PDzNee9x2uLBq0Gaf45wqpXjlTdm3T4WVzcxedjwitF3aJjn7vLrQ@TDhweiTI34)

PCRE **R**eplace all those with nothing

---

44 byte version not using RegEx or strange character literals (and thus single byte per character):

```apl
⍞~⎕UCS∊65055 8399 7615 6831 767+⍳¨16×2 6~⍨⍳7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#DYy9asJgGIX3XMW3u5hKvugcRJfiUL2AD7RTaSAXIIWAxtQIoiEaa2mL9Weq4uIm1PU9N/HeSHyn55zDw@FoGBScfPZ5kna8J45i7ZQdR1UrtZpyte0oXa3YktwSJ@f/va1v2YPSfU720t2Co2ERWM06tsjpomjmYdSiDCmFjxhjiUGd3inEbxtj@kLapA39YWUFlogU@12a9TDHWtGggTeaYufj4wVzkeJnjJCIaYzBDgcjp0dDC8FUljV@KBdmwqtYt9MrhULOvzncqDs)
`⍳7` 1…7 (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)

`2 6~⍨` except 2 and 6 (1 3 4 5 7)

`16×` multiply by 16 (16 48 64 80 112)

`⍳¨` 1… each (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16, 1 2 3…, …110 111 112)

`+` add offset to each list (65056 65057 65058…, …877 878 879)

`∊` enlist (flatten)

`⎕UCS` convert to corresponding Unicode character

`⍞~` get text input and remove all such characters

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 bytes

```
“Żȷ'⁺¦60ƭṖ_WTɦ7Ụ|ṫYɠF’bȷ5r2/FỌḟ@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AXQAi/9qZWxsef//4oCcxbvItyfigbrCpjYwxq3huZZfV1TJpjfhu6R84bmrWcmgRuKAmWLItzVyMi9G4buM4bifQP///yJIRc2mzZrMuCDMk0PNiU/Ml82VzINNzYzNmc2GRcyLzIPNpVTNjMygzZVIzKTMr82bIg)

## Explanation

```
“Żȷ'⁺¦60ƭṖ_WTɦ7Ụ|ṫYɠF’bȷ5r2/FỌḟ@  Main link
“Żȷ'⁺¦60ƭṖ_WTɦ7Ụ|ṫYɠF’            Base 250 compressed integer; 768008790683206911076160767908400084476505665071
                      bȷ5         Convert into base 100000; [768, 879, 6832, 6911, 7616, 7679, 8400, 8447, 65056, 65071]
                         r2/      Inclusive range on non-overlapping slices of length 2
                            F     Flatten
                             Ọ    chr; cast to character from codepoints
                              ḟ@  Filter; remove all characters from input that are in the characters generated before
```

Comment: o0 Didn't realize I bumped this question up lol. Is that `b65072` what I think it is? :o

Comment: @icrieverytim yes numerical list compression :D

Comment: jelly is definitely the most zalgo language. i wonder what would happen if you ran the program on its own code? edit: unfortunately nothing

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 57 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("[̀-ͯ᪰-᫿᷀-᷿⃐-⃿︠-︯]","")
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY/PSgJRFMb3PcVhVjPQzAtIQYTkRlvUTlzcxjHGxjuDMwoRgjAgaAaJimUJFpZUC22lu1m0PechZl7AR5huNdsQzuU79/z53e@WWZ2ptmPwcvEi1i3mupBlJr/aATC5Z1RLTDcg93MFOPGqJj8HXU4SV0mJekMcEa7HPFOHHHDYg9hV912tajiWWD@wLFnKY1OlRfi@VMOPIFw11XAVRP6tGvnBZj1VN@tFQdqVJCVO/eGc2pklcAm1bptFqAhfydP5AjAlMXXpekZFs2ue5oiWZ3GZa7osZdL0SmNcA/YPqX2MIxqin6Uu3VMrjdfo08spdXFKwwzOcEEPkvL7nf@JAoMdu4h9gwY0AWwdURN7NLfp0aKBQHRK1KabrRzGGM3pjQlDS4Z3QnqiMqFnHAsdCQ22Mr4@Ofpbp6LxU@TPkrHGTiP@Bg)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 32 bytes

```
•3xIαEλ¤’ä₆Ćkмм`0Â9"´•žHв2ôvyŸçK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWcAmP8wNWFiMWX//@KAojN4Sc6xRc67wqTigJnDpOKChsSGa9C80LxgMMOCOSLCtOKAosW@SNCyMsO0dnnFuMOnS///Q82JzIpvZMyTZc2UzZ0gzIZHzYDMkc2nb82cbM2UzK/NimbNic2N)